# How to share eventLoop between outbound-channel (from ChannelPoolMap) and inbound-channel for proxy like application

Tags: netty

With reference to http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-twitter-meetup-netty/slides.html#20.0, for proxy like application (`HTTP client -> proxy-server (netty) -> remote HTTP server`), how to share `eventLoop` between `outbound-channel` (which get acquired from ChannelPoolMap for proxy-server -> remote HTTP server) and `inbound-channel` (HTTP client -> proxy-server)?

`ChannelPoolMap` impl would look like:

```
val bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
if (sys.props.get("os.name").get == "Linux") {
  bootstrap.group(new EpollEventLoopGroup())
  bootstrap.channel(classOf[EpollSocketChannel])
} else {
  bootstrap.group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
  bootstrap.channel(classOf[NioSocketChannel])
}
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
val connectionsPoolMap = new AbstractChannelPoolMap[InetSocketAddress, SimpleChannelPool]() {
  override protected def newPool(key: InetSocketAddress): SimpleChannelPool = {
    return new SimpleChannelPool(bootstrap.remoteAddress(key), new CountingChannelPoolHandler)
  }
}
```

and in inbound-channel handler, `channelActive` would look like

```
override def channelActive(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext) = {
    val inboundChannel = ctx.channel
    val pool = poolMap.iterator.next.getValue
    outboundChannel = pool.acquire.sync.getNow
    if (outboundChannel.pipeline.get("sbh") != null) {
      outboundChannel.pipeline.remove("sbh")
    }
    outboundChannel.pipeline.addLast("sbh", new SBH(inboundChannel))
    inboundChannel.read()
}
```

Here, how to share `inboundChannel.eventLoop()` with `outboundChannel` so that all IO for both connected Channels are handled by the same Thread?
If i don't use `ChannelPoolMap` then i can create `Bootstrap` and assign `inboundChannel.eventLoop()` to `Bootstrap#group` as like how it is explained in slide #20

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

Setup the server side of the proxy:

```
bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(NUMB_OF_THREADS);
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();        
serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
// Add more options for serverBootstrap if you want
```

A ChannelPool needs to be instantiated with an EventLoopGroup, and IT HAS to be one of the EventLoopGroups that the server uses, if you're building a proxy. The idea is to populate a map with ChannelPools, where each ChannelPool corresponds to a thread from the workerGroup. For that, I used as keys to the poolMap the underlying threads of the workerGroup.

```
ChannelPoolMap<EventExecutor, SimpleChannelPool> poolMap = new AbstractChannelPoolMap<EventExecutor, SimpleChannelPool>() {
   @Override
   protected SimpleChannelPool newPool(EventExecutor key) {

      Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();
      clientBootstrap.group((EventLoopGroup) key).channel(NioSocketChannel.class); 
      // add more options related to clientBootstrap here... 

      return new SimpleChannelPool(clientBootstrap.remoteAddress(REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT), new ChannelPoolHandler() { // implement abstract methods });
   }
}
```

Now, populate the poolMap by adding a new ChannelPool for each of the EventExecutors from the workerGroup

```
Iterator<EventExecutor> iter = workerGroup.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) { // will add to the poolMap a Connection Pool, one for each thread of the workerGroup
    poolMap.get(iter.next());
}
```

Finally, at the class where you handle an incoming connection, you'd acquire the corresponding Channel Pool. You get the underlying EventLoopGroup of the inboundChannel, and use that as a key to fetch the corresponding Channel Pool.

```
final Future<Channel> futChan = poolMap.get(inboundChannel.eventLoop()).acquire();
```

Personally, I used the HexDumpProxy example from Netty's git repository to start building my own version of a proxy.